# Cant extract text properly into list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a list of files that I would like the extract the text from each one and put the text for each file in a separete list. Although, the output comes out as strings which makes it hard for me to separate which text belongs to which file.

-----------this is the file list:

```
[WindowsPath('C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/test_folder/final test.txt'),  WindowsPath('C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/test_folder/iptest.txt'), WindowsPath('C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/test_folder/New Text Document.txt'), WindowsPath('C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/test_folder/test2.txt')]
```

-----------The output i am getting is:

```
rgerg



egfreg



secret

dafreagr 343.23.12.53.100 aefref
secret

grre

regreg



ergre
```

test is working

-----------I would like the output to be:

```
[['rgerg','egfreg','secret'],
['dafreagr 343.23.12.53.100 aefref'],
['secret','grre','regreg','ergre'],
['test is working']]
```

------------OR, separte lists is possible:

```
['rgerg','egfreg','secret']
['dafreagr 343.23.12.53.100 aefref']
['secret','grre','regreg','ergre']
['test is working']
```

-------------I have a function "loader()"that  currently extracts the file's text:

```
 for items in txt_files:
   for item in loader(items):
    words = item
    print(words)
```

I was unable to get my desired output with both a list and dictionary. Not sure how I should go about this.

UPDATED OUTPUT:

items output:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
```

Item output:

```
S
e
c
r
e
t












S
e
c
r
e
t

t
h
i
s

i
s

a

t
e
s
t

d
o
c
u
m
e
n
t

f
o
r

k
e
y
w
o
r
d

s
c
a
n
s
.




T
h
i
s

i
s

a

t
e
s
t
.




S
e
c
r
e
t
s
e
c
r
e
t
```

Comment: add the content in file in your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a `result` list and then append data to it.

**Ex:**

```
result = []
for items in txt_files:
    temp = []
    for item in loader(items):
        temp.append(item)
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

**Edit as per comment**

```
result = []
for items in txt_files:
    result.append(loader(items).splitlines())
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but now its outputting like this:

Comment: [['S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', ' ', 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', ' ', 's', 'c', 'a', 'n', 's', '.', '\n', '\n', 'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '.', '\n', '\n', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't'], ['s', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't']]

Comment: This is 'items' output. It was too long to post as a comment. but bascially its both files just repeated for the amount of items in the lists

C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\secretwe.docx

Comment: and as for 'item' the output was each letter of the file on a separate line, spelled out vertically.                                                                                                          S
e
c
r
e
t